# What would make a composite chemical vapor deposition diamond hard to make?

Tags: electrical-engineering, materials, chemical-engineering

I am exploring whether a diamond based capacitor could be made for powering a drone. From my initial research, it has the right material properties (thermal conductivity, strength to weight ratio, dielectric strength), but I know from experience that doesn't mean it can be made. I found that the only practical way of making the near flawless diamonds are through chemical vapor deposition techniques. Since the capacitor would need to have conductive plates that sandwich the diamond, it would make the part a composite.

So I am here to ask the question:

What would make a composite chemical vapor deposition diamond hard to make?

From my initial thinking about it, it seems that mating the two layers chemically would be difficult, as diamond is quite inert and doesn't want to bond to the conductive metals needed for the electrodes. But, if carbon, like graphite or graphene is used, I think it could work since the whole capacitor would essentially be the same element, just configured differently. The size of the capacitor would be 0.1 cc, so I think most vacuum chambers already in existence would be able to make the part.

Is this doable with current technology, or are we missing something that makes this not possible currently?